# npm install errors out preinstall script

Tags: javascript, npm, npx

I needed to fix security vulnerabilities for knexnest > knex > minimist. The version for minimist did not get updated with **npm audit fix** or simple **npm update**. I followed [this article](https://itnext.io/fixing-security-vulnerabilities-in-npm-dependencies-in-less-than-3-mins-a53af735261d) and it updated the versions and gave a vulnerability score of 0. But now when I create a docker image (build) my repo, it fails at the preinstall script.

```
npx: installed 5 in 5.29s
EACCES: permission denied, open './package-lock.json'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-service@1.2.3 preinstall: `npx npm-force-resolutions`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-service@1.2.3 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/node/.npm/_logs/2020-07-15T09_56_56_625Z-debug.log
```

While installing modules locally on editor, no errors pop up. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error, I fixed it with

```
chmod 666 package-lock.json
```

This doesn't seem as a root cause solution, but it's a simple workaround.